# Update Neo4J DB using PHP

Tags: php, neo4j

I need to add a admin user to label admin. the label is already exist and just need to be updated in the DB.
i tryed this code (but it didn't work):

```
$client = DbConfig::getDbClient();
$nodeIndex = new NodeIndex($client,"Admin");
$admin = $client->makeNode()->setProperty('name', 'admin name')->save();
$nodeIndex->add($admin, 'name', $admin->getProperty('name'));
```

I'm not sure if this is possible and if it is the right way but still its not working.

Comment: Please add further detail about what you are trying to do. What language driver are you using? Is there a Cypher query you are trying to translate into PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see that you are using a non-updated neo4j driver. While we respect all the work done so far, neo4j is evolving a lot and maybe the driver author has no time anymore to invest in it.

I would first suggest that you take a look in general at the documentation about the Cypher query language, which is what drivers may produce under the hood.

http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/cypher-query-lang.html

The methods you are using are referring to the legacy index usage. I would suggest that you take a look at the neo4j documentation about Schema Indexes :

http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-schema-index.html

You can still use the same driver for issuing Cypher requests, just you'll need to adapt the methods.

Or you can use an up-to-dated driver, a nice example tutorial has been written on Sitepoint for using neo4j and php :

http://www.sitepoint.com/discover-graph-databases-neo4j-php/